# Cucumber-jvm - Retrieving embedded image from TestCaseFinished event

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a cucumber plugin where I post my test case results to TestRail using the TestCaseFinished event. It works so far, but on failed steps, I use the scenario.embed method to add a screenshot of the failed step. The TestCaseFinished event does not contain this (or the scenario.write method)

Is there any way to retrieve this information using a cucumber plugin? I considered, during the @After hook, when taking the screenshot, to save the image temporarily in the target directory but this seems like a long drawn out process, when it seems like it should be available in the event. If not, any particular reason why it isn't included?

Comment: Try listening for `EmbedEvent` and `WriteEvent`.

Comment: Tried that, but the embed event doesn't contain the scenario the screenshot is attached to. I was originally using that event to save each embedded event (screenshot always) and then I'd reference the directory for each failed case during TestCaseFinished. This seems quite complex though, was hoping that TestCaseFinished would have an easy way to reference it.

Comment: Agggh, I see it does have getTestCase() after all. How'd I miss that! I'll work with that now. Thanks for your response @mpkorstanje